# Not able to load the ext-all.js file

Tags: javascript, eclipse, tomcat, extjs, extjs4

i have a couple of questions:

first i want to describe the things i am using.

1) Dynamic project.
2) using tomcat - 7.
3) put the extjs folder in WebContent folder.

i am just learning the things ... so might be have some stupid questions .. sorry for that.

[image]

[image]

so i have confusion that ext-all.js not uploaded ...might be because of one of the reason...

1) Use of tomcat (instead i need to use apache) .... please give me some explanation on that.
2) i need to put extjs folder somewhere else ... (not sure about this).

Please help

Comment: Highly unlikely but will ask anyway - is the website you have setup allowed to serve CSS and Js files? I would have thought answer is yes as these are pretty standard but worth checking in case

Comment: Actually No , later i will add java code(spring and hibernate) too... :)

Answer (score 1):

May or may not be the answer.
Try putting ./ infront of the path

```
<script src="./extjs/ext-all.js" type="text/javascript"/>
```

You didn't include the location of your html file, so their is no way of knowing where you have to point the script tag to.

Hope this helps a little

Cheers,

Demetry